# Delay explorer on start up

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, my-documents

I have an issue where an employee's computer does not have their "My Doc's" on startup. After going through various testing I have determined that the issue is residing with the explorer shell loading the my docs before it actually has network connectivity (their documents resided on a file server).

I came to this conclusion because:

1) Registry key properly points the employees my docs to the server/location

2) group policy has been verified and folder redirection has no errors

3) In any Office program, when the user goes to open a document or attach a file in an email, the file explorer that is opened properly displays their my docs

4) stopping the explorer process and restarting it after the user has logged will load the user's my docs.

I am thinking about writing a bat file that the user can click on to stop and restart the explorer shell, however I would much rather delay explorer from loading before the connection is established or possibly make it so that explorer constantly refreshes.

Also, if anyone has any ideas as to possible sources of this issue I would love to hear it.

Comment: Check to make sure that ControlPanel-> SynchCenter -> Manage Offline Files is set to disable offline file synch. It doesn't seem to mix well with redirected folders in some appeareently random circumstances.

Comment: @FrankThomas I have just checked the synch center settings, and it was already set to disable offline files.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are having an asynchronous fast logon issue with folder redirection. You may want to disable that and use "Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon" group policy.

Open the Group Policy Object Editor.

Under Computer Configuration in the navigation tree on the left side, navigate to Administrative Templates\System\Logon. Here you can simply enable (or disable) the setting.

Here's the source of the above information with pictures if links works for you:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg486839.aspx